# Ionic 2 Angular 2 Global Import Extension methods

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

I've made some extensions to the Date prototype like:

```
interface Date {
    YearsFromToday(): number;
}

Date.prototype.YearsFromToday = function (): number {
    // implementation 
}
```

I'm using the ionic2 tutorial --v2 template, which is a pretty standard layout - app.html, app.ts, app.module etc.

I was wondering if there was an easy way to have this declared globally. I'm not sure exactly where to put this in the project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put your monkey patch code in a file.
You might call it **monkey-patch-date.ts**, for example:

**monkey-patch-date.ts**

```
interface Date {
    YearsFromToday(): number;
}

Date.prototype.yearsFromToday = function (): number {
    // implementation 
}
```

and then import it in **main.ts** or whatever your entry module is:

**main.ts**

```
import './monkey-patch-date';
```

Alternately. You can make it a module that exports its monkey-patcher if you want to be extra explicit to call out that you are doing something dangerous.

**monkey-patch-date.ts**

```
declare global {
    interface Date {
        yearsFromToday(): number;
    }
}

export default function () {
    Date.prototype.yearsFromToday = function (): number {
        // implementation 
    };
}
```

And import it like

**main.ts**

```
import monkeyPatchDate from './monkey-patch-date';
monkeyPatchDate();
```

Another alternative, especially useful for library authors is to allow monkey-patching but not require it while still exposing the functionality.

Here is an example:

**date-augmentations/index.ts**

```
export function yearsFromToday(date: Date): number {
    // implementation 
}
```

**date-augmentations/monkey-patch.ts**

```
import {yearsFromToday} from './index';

declare global {
    interface Date {
        yearsFromToday(): number;
    }
}

Date.prototype.yearsFromToday = function() {
    return yearsFromToday(this);
}
```

Now a consumer can either monkey patch the Date prototype by running

```
import 'date-augmentations/monkey-patch';
```

Can access the functionality by the export without monkey patching anything

```
import {yearsFromToday} from 'date-augmentations';

const date = new Date('12-12-2023');
const yft = yearsFromToday(date);
console.log(yft); // prints 6
```

Comment: Thanks I'll check this out when I get back home

Comment: @johnny5 I added some additional information you may find useful if you need to write libraries or experience conflicts.